# Angular bootstrap navbar compatibility question

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am using Angular15.0.3, Bootstap4.0.0.
My dropdown shows as the below image - i.e doesn't display the Save option.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button">
        Dropdown
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Save</a></li>
      </ul> 
    </li>
    
   
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my Angular.json:

```
 "styles": [
                  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                  "src/styles.css"
                ],
                "scripts": [
                  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                ]
```

I didnt install or add popper.js /jquery.js separately as the bootstrap.bundle.min.js is supposed to inline both of them.

```
For reference, my versions 
"bootstrap": "^5.2.3"
"@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Bootstrap 4 requires scripts to work. For example:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

If you add those to your index.html it will work. However, a MUCH better choice would be to use NG Bootstrap which doesn't require jQuery.  https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Comment: The answer seems to be correct, unfortunately didnt work.